# “She waited for me for two hours” “She had been waiting for me for two hours”

Tags: difference, past-tense, past-continuous

> She waited for me for two hours

> She had been waiting for me for two hours

Which statement is more correct? And how do we know which statement we should use?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, and have (more or less) the same literal meaning, but their connotations are different.

> She waited for me for two hours[.]

This is a complete sentence, and it stands alone. The simple past describes an event that happened in the past, and which is now over and done with. She began waiting, and then (after two hours had elapsed) she stopped waiting, either because you arrived or because she got tired of waiting. Nothing much of interest happened during that two-hour period.

> She had been waiting for me for two hours

While this *can* be a complete sentence by itself, the past perfect connotes that something happened during that two hours, which you are about to tell us about (or have just told us about), so it would be more common to write something like this:

> She had been waiting for me for two hours **when I called her.**

> **I called her, and** she had been waiting for me for two hours.

You could also write this as multiple sentences. As shown above, the intervening event is usually in the simple past.